# Unlocking iPad Purchased from Government

Tags: ios, ipad, user-account, administrator, ipados

I have an iPad that was purchased from a previous employer (government local council). I have tried to factory reset it, but when setting up, I am told that this needs to be completed by the administrators for the council that I used to work for. Is there anyway of getting around this, without talking to the administrators from my previous employer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Governments tend to use MDMs, or Mobile Device Management systems. So the only way to deal with this is to get them to remove the device from their MDM. The only way to do that would be to talk to them.

If, of course, you purchased this iPad legitimately, there would be no issue in doing this. There would be a process in place for removal of a device from MDM.

Comment: If it's re-enrolling itself in MDM after a factory reset, that means it's enrolled in Apple's device enrollment program (DEP), and must be removed from that. Instructions for removing it from DEP are [here](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/guide/apple-business-manager/asmec4d28461/web) (note: these are instructions for the business's MDM admin to follow; you can't do it yourself).

Comment: Ah yes, I'd forgotten about DEP. Thanks.